# jQuery UI Autocomplete on Chrome not honoring select function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui

On my page, I have two fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="NewRecipientCode" name="NBC" value="" />
<div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBox("NewRecipientName", "", new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
```

I make the NewRecipientName into an autocomplete field with jQuery:

```
$('#NewRecipientName').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 500,
    source: '/api/Recipient/',
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item);
        $('#NewRecipientCode').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#NewRecipientName').val(ui.item.label)
    }
});
```

<del>This works fine in IE and FireFox. However, when I run it in Chrome,</del>  When I run this code it only populates the fields with the ui.item.value value, ignoring the label completely. I haven't been able to find an answer to why it is broken <del>in Chrome</del>. Looking at the value of the field in the Inspector, it is never set.

I run jQuery 3.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1. My Chrome browser is 60.0.3112.113m, my FireFox is 55.0.3 and IE is 11.0.9600.18762.

Comment: delete your browsing data (history) often causes browser cache problems

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. jQuery still inserts the Recipient Code in both fields.